# How do I solder "cable shoes" onto a circuit board?

Tags: pcb

I've got a timer (http://m.ebay.co.uk/itm/221094671882) with male cable shoe connectors (see image). I've connected the timer with other devices using wires w/female cable shoe connectors.

[image: Example cable shoe connectors]

*Cable shoe connector example.*

I'd like to attach the timer directly to a circuit board of my own design. What type of connector do I solder onto the circuit board? Should I just take any female connector, strip off the plastic coating, and solder it onto the board...or is there a more specific product for this?

Comment: The term "cable shoe" seems to refer to various types of crimp terminal such as ring or spade. Can you link to a datasheet or photo for clarity?

Comment: What are "cable shoes"? Can you show us a picture?

Comment: Do you have a datasheet for the timer?

Comment: Added link to the timer in question.

Comment: The type of cable shoe I currently use is https://www.google.com/search?q=cable+shoe&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ei=VQLhU8K7HcOgyAOLxYD4DQ&ved=0CAcQ_AUoAQ&biw=320&bih=460#facrc=_&imgrc=zIv6LJhosWUeqM%253A%3BRzAtAwG5arcAPM%3Bhttp%253A%252F%252Fwww.toplicht.de%252Fthumbs%252Ftbn_2212021.JPG%3Bhttp%253A%252F%252Fwww.toplicht.de%252Fen%252Fshop%252Fbordelektrik-und-elektronik%252Fkabel-und-zubehoer%252Fkabelschuh%3B106%3B204

Comment: Cable shoes are apparently spade terminal connectors. I'll add an image to the OP.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You want a female quick connect tab, PCB mount, vertical. Something like this, but check the width is correct, they come in different widths.

[image: vertical PCB receptacle]

http://www.keyelco.com/product.cfm/Vertical-Entry/3575/product_id/678

TE call them [Fast-on tabs](http://www.te.com/catalog/menu/en/17703) for the male, receptacles for the female. I've been in the electronics industry 24  years and have never heard them called "cable shoes".

Comment: Cable shoes might just be a local language specific term I unknowingly translated to english. Anyway, what you've suggested seems to be a perfect match. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

It's not clear what exactly your connector is, but one elegant way to handle this may be with a "through hole" style "barrier terminal block", which would mount to normal holes in your pcb.

[image]